# CSS background Div

Tags: css, html

I have a page full of divs, but I am here to talk about one special div.  I want this div to appear in the background. I want it to only be seen when there is no div in front of it. I don't want it to resize for other divs. Think of it like a background image, except it is a div. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Look at the `z-index` property.

Comment: you should use the css `background-image` style on the `body` if you want background images. That's way easier.

Answer (score 0):

you could apply the css style z-index on the div

```
.div{
z-index:-1;
}
```

the z-index is responsible for the order in which the elements appear setting this to something like -1 means that if there is any other div in front of this div they would appear in front assuming they don't have a z-index less than -1 for example:http://jsfiddle.net/J49b3/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jboneca/p5Rz2/1/) to get you started. You can think of the `z-index` property as layers; A higher z-index will bring that "layer" toward the front, and a lower one will send it toward the back.

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) more info on z-index.